Unexpected token error while creating route-table route using azure cli
Using azure cli from azure devops ci/cd pipeline
In azure virtual network, created a new route table, now trying to create a route
                - task: AzureCLI@2
                  displayName: 'Route'
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: subscription
                    scriptType: ps
                    scriptLocation: inlineScript
                    inlineScript: |
                      az network route-table route create `
                      --resource-group myrg `
                      --route-table-name test `
                      --name vnetroute `
                      --next-hop-type VirtualAppliance `
                      --address-prefix 0.0.0.0/0 `
                      --next-hop-ip-address 0.0.0.0

and getting this error -
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1712679912359_inlinescript.ps1:3 char:3
+ --route-table-name test `
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1712679912359_inlinescript.ps1:3 char:3
+ --route-table-name test `
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'route-table-name' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

Can someone help please?

The same Azure CLI command works in my pipeline. Can you please double check if you have shared the issue-reproducible YAML contents? By the way, may I know if you used any variable value following the statement --route-table-name? If yes, please provide the complete script and workflow to help understand how the variable value was generated? Hope the information helps.

The same Azure CLI command was working in my pipeline and local PowerShell. In addition, I could only reproduce the issue if the line breaker ` was missing like the script below.
# "--resource-group myrg" before "--route-table-name test" missing line breaker `

az network route-table route create `
--resource-group myrg
--route-table-name test `
--name vnetroute `
--next-hop-type VirtualAppliance `
--address-prefix 0.0.0.0/0 `
--next-hop-ip-address 0.0.0.0



Please double check your inline script or if you have shared the issue-reproducible YAML contents. There might be a chance that you shared the working script in the YAML file from one branch and your pipeline was referencing the YAML definition from another branch, where the wrong script located.

It was just a space which was causing issue lol, thank you for your help. :)

Glad to hear you have figured out the little bug in the script. Cheers!
